# Maven: is it possible to specify a different version of a same plugin for multiple profiles, while activating all those profiles at the same time?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a Maven project in which I've created some API definitions with Swagger. Using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`, I'm generating both JAVA code and TypeScript code to use the API.

In my `pom.xml` configuration, I've defined a Maven profile for each language. Thing is I'd like to use version 4.2.0 of this plugin when generating JAVA code, and version 4.3.0 when generating TypeScript code: I was using version 4.2.0 in both profile but some new features appeared in version 4.3.0 for TypeScript generation, and after some tests, I figured there were some side-effects I'd like to avoid for JAVA generation.

When each profile is activated on its own, everything is working as expected. 
**But if I activate both profiles, Maven is using the most recent version of the plugin: 4.3.0.**

As my Maven project will be built in a CI/CD server, I was wondering if it was possible to use a specific version of a same maven plugin on a profile basis during a single build, or do I need to create a separate build for each profile?

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>java</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-api-java-model</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                ...
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>typescript</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-api-ts-model</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                              ...
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: The question is why you think is necessary...to have different versions active in one build?

Comment: The maintainers of this plugin added some new configuration attributes specific to TypeScript in version 4.3.0. But in the meantime, they're introduced some minor changes that could been seen as side-effects for other languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there can only be one plugin version per build.